# Is there a way in Mozilla Firefox to show full drop down list like it is in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

As the question in title already says I am trying to find a way for Firefox browser, to show whole drop-down list(select field with options) - without a scrollbar. (Same as it is in Internet Explorer).
At the moment full drop-down list is displayed only then when view-port height is in the size of drop-down list, otherwise Firefox returns a scroll-able list. I am not a fan of setting the window size static as Javascript appends the options to select field and the count of options can change.

Is it even possible to hide scrollbar and show all of the options at once for Firefox browser ?

If there isn't a way I was thinking maybe I can use Javascript to count the options in drop-down list and then use window.innerHeight to resize the window afterwards.
What are the options to solve this ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can count options and set `size` attribute of `select` element to match options' count. But, FF doesn't fit the position of the oversized list like IE tries to do.